# Evaluate $I_n= \int_{1}^{2} x^n\frac{x^2-4}{x^2+4}\,\rm{d} x$

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, definite-integrals

> Consider the following function
>
> $$ f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R, \qquad f(x)=\frac{x^2-4}{x^2+4} $$
>
> and also the following integral
>
> $$I_n= \int_{1}^{2} x^n f(x) \,\rm{d} x$$
>
> Show that $\lim_{n \to \infty} I_n = -\infty$.

---

Now, the problem that i have is with $x^n$ , i was thinking that this can be do by parts . Could you help me out ?

Comment: Is the number in the numerator $2$ or $4$? In the title you have $4$ but in the question you have $2$. If it is $4$ then I have an answer. If it is $2$ then the limit is actually $+\infty$. So I suspect it is meant to be $4$.

Comment: It is 4, my bad . Sorry ! I will correct now

Comment: In that case you can just say that $x^n f(x) \leq 0$ for $x \in [1,2]$ and $f(x) \leq c$ for $x \in [1,2-\delta]$ where $c<0$ (neither $c$ nor $\delta$ depend on $n$). Then you're good to go. You don't need to explicitly integrate $x^n f(x)$.

Comment: @Ian Why have you deleted your answer?

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net Initially because I wasn't sure about this 2 vs 4 issue. Now I'm torn about whether I think the OP has enough of an attempt for a full answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easier than that. First note that $x^n f(x) \leq 0$, so discarding part of the domain makes the integral larger (more positive). Now the simplest thing to do would be to say that $\frac{x^2-4}{x^2+4}$ is less than a negative constant on all of $[1,2]$, but this doesn't quite work because it vanishes at $x=2$. But if you cut out a neighborhood of $x=2$ then you can do this, so you can pick $c$ and $\delta$ independent of $n$ (but dependent on each other) such that $I_n \leq \int_1^{2-\delta} cx^n dx$. Now you're good to go.